# is there a good way to call methods dynamically in js?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 js functions:

```
function onRegionMouseOver()
{
}

function onRegionMouseOut()
{
}
```

Is it possible to call these js functions dynamically doing something like this?:

```
var type = 'Out'
//the following line would exec onRegionMouseOut() above:
call(onRegionMouse[type]())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var onRegionMouseHandlers = {
  out: function () {},
  in: function () {}
}

// and using like this
var whatToUse = 'in';
// use
onRegionMouseHandlers[whatToUse]()
```

Also, you can remove your which choose what function have to be called. You can just add two handlers to two different events.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the functions as properties of an object, use bracket notation to call the function.

```js
const methods = {
  onRegionMouseOver() {console.log("Over")},
  onRegionMouseOut() {console.log("Out")}
}

let fn = "onRegionMouse";

let type = "Out";

methods[`${fn}${type}`]();

type = "Over";

methods[`${fn}${type}`]();
```

without template literal or `let`

```js
var methods = {
  onRegionMouseOver: function onRegionMouseOver() {console.log("Over")},
  onRegionMouseOut: function onRegionMouseOu() {console.log("Out")}
}

var fn = "onRegionMouse";

var type = "Out";

methods[fn + type]();

type = "Over";

methods[fn + type]();
```

Comment: Note that this string definition notation (template literals? don't know how to name this correctly) will work only on a few modern browsers. Or you need transpile this code. Same for `let` keyword

Comment: I think it will be nice if you will mention _why_ you give 2 variants: modern and not-modern.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Not certain if "modern" is the appropriate description of  possible variants at Answer, or why two variants are provided at Answer. Rather, 1) access to FOSS browser; 2)  consistently updating to newest version of FOSS browser. Where the above might not be possible at 1); or user simply not performing consistent updates at 2).

Comment: You really should use just `fn+type` instead of string interpolation or `concat`.

Comment: @Bergi The reason being? Greater overall usage capability?

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough.

Comment: @Bergi If you are aware, what is the range of current support for defining a function with shorthand at an object? Or are you only referencing text within bracket notation as to shorter code?

Comment: @guest271314 No idea. I'd check caniuse and kangax' compat table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, provided you declare an object that contains the functions.

```
var onRegionMouse = {
   Out: onRegionMouseOut,
   Over: onRegionMouseOver
};
```

Now you can just do

```
var type = 'Out';
onRegionMouse[type]();
```

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
var myFunctions = {
   out: function onMouseOut()...,
   enter: function onMouseEnter()...
}
```

You can call it now with myFunctions[ "out" ] ()

Comment: There were already 3 similar answers, 2 of them identical to yours.

Comment: Oups, when I answered the question has no answers